# Sort Javascript array containing objects by key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, nested

I'm trying to sort the next array alphabetically by the data keys:

```
array = [
{index: 1,
 data: "d"
},
{index: 2,
 data: "c"
},
{index: 3,
 data: "a"
},
{index: 4,
 data: "f"
},
{index: 5,
 data: "e"
},
{index: 6,
 data: "b"
}
];
```

such that it will become as follows:

```
array = [
{index: 3,
 data: "a"
},
{index: 6,
 data: "b"
},
{index: 2,
 data: "c"
},
{index: 1,
 data: "d"
},
{index: 5,
 data: "e"
},
{index: 4,
 data: "f"
}
];
```

Already found and tried something like this:

```
array.sort(function (a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; });
```

but with no success. Is there a simple way to achieve this? Pure js please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort by property `data` with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
var array = [{ index: 1, data: "d" }, { index: 2, data: "c" }, { index: 3, data: "a" }, { index: 4, data: "f" }, { index: 5, data: "e" }, { index: 6, data: "b" }];

array.sort(function (a, b) { return a.data.localeCompare(b.data); });
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access by key not by index

```js
let array = [{index: 1, data: "d"},{index: 2, data: "c"},{index: 3, data: "a"},{index: 4, data: "f"},{index: 5, data: "e"},{index: 6, data: "b"}];

array.sort( (f, s) => f.data.localeCompare(s.data) );

console.log(array);
```